# Getting multiple entries for SELECT DISTINCT sqlite android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to get the unique column name and show it as a list adapter.

```
public String[] getAllUsers() {
        String[] contactList = new String[100];

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(true,TABLE_TRANS, new String[] { KEY_ID ,KEY_NAME, KEY_CASH,KEY_DESC,KEY_DATE }, null, null, KEY_NAME, null, null, null);
      int i=0;
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {               
                contactList[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                i++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;

    }
```

The above is method in my database class.

And from mainActivity I call this method

```
private void updateUserList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] contactList = new String[100];
    contactList = db.getAllUsers();
            Log.d("User List",contactList[0]);
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The list is getting updated ,but list is getting repeated as a whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understood your question.

If you want to get columns `KEY_ID ,KEY_NAME, KEY_CASH,KEY_DESC,KEY_DATE` from all rows in database without `KEY_NAME` repetitions use this query:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true,TABLE_TRANS, 
                new String[] { KEY_ID ,KEY_NAME, KEY_CASH,KEY_DESC,KEY_DATE },
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

In your methods do not use `Array` instead use `ArrayList<String>`

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllUsers() {
    ArrayList<String> contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true,TABLE_TRANS,
                    new String[] { KEY_ID ,KEY_NAME, KEY_CASH,KEY_DESC,KEY_DATE },
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {               
            contactList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;

}
```

And updateUserList():

```
private void updateUserList() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

ArrayList<String> contactList;

contactList = db.getAllUsers();
        Log.d("User List", contactList.get(0));
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

As you only use the column KEY_NAME from cursor the query can be simplified to return only that column.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(true,TABLE_TRANS, 
                new String[] {KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with initializing the String array as 100. I wrote a method to get the total number of counts and it works fine.

```
public int getUsersCount() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(true,TABLE_TRANS, new String[] { KEY_ID ,KEY_NAME, KEY_CASH,KEY_DESC,KEY_DATE }, null, null, KEY_NAME, null, null, null);
        //cursor.close(); 
        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();}
```